# Set object in SequelizeJS function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I'd like to get all my projects in the `findAll()` function of `SequelizeJS` but it seem's not working outside the function...

```js
var myProjects;
Project.findAll().then(function(projects) {
  myProjects = projects;
});
console.log(myProjects); // it doesn't work
```

**EDIT #2**

I'm trying to create an object containing all my links that I can get on each views without calling `findAll()` on each actions... `projects` was an example, but the real context is on my link's model !

```js
var dbContext = require('./../../db/DbContext');
var _ = require('lodash');

var LinkDao = function () {
  this.context = dbContext.entities;
};

_.extend(LinkDao.prototype, {
  
  getAllByOrder: function (callback) {
    return this.context.Link.findAll({order: 'position ASC', include: [{ model: this.context.Link}], where: {type: [0,1]}});
  },

});

module.exports = LinkDao;
```

```js
exports.locals = function(app){
  app.use(function(request, response, next){
    var linkDao = new LinkDao();
    linkDao.getAllByOrder().success( function(links){
      response.locals.navLinks = links;
    });
    var ecCategoryDao = new EcCategoryDao();
    ecCategoryDao.getAll().success( function(ecCategories) {
      response.locals.ecCategories = ecCategories;
      next(); // navLinks is not accessible
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<% navLinks.forEach(function(link){ %>
 <% if(link.type === 0) { %>
 <li><a href="/"><%-link.name%></a></li>
 <li class="top-bar-divider"></li>
 <% } else { %>
 <li><a href="<%-link.pointer%>"><%-link.name%></a></li>
 <li class="top-bar-divider"></li>
 <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: That won't work. The .then is a promise callback that won't execute until findAll has completed. You would have to put the code that you want executed in that function. It's best to read up on the asynchronous nature of Javascript.

Comment: Ok but, Is there any other way to get the object outside of the function? Maybe a synchronous function of SequeliseJS?

Comment: I don't think there is a synchronous version looking at the docs. I'd suggest analyzing exactly what it is you want to accomplish, and then refactor your code. Maybe post more of your code so we can see the context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: See edit#1 for the real context...

Comment: Doesn't work, see edit#2 with two queries...